# How to find the number of compound divisors of the smallest product from two unknown numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, divisibility, prime-factorization

The problem is as follows:

> The number of panadol pills at a pharmacy is a positive whole number
> that it has two prime divisors and 45 positive divisors. The number of
> tylenol pills at the same pharmacy is also a positive whole number
> which has 66 positive divisors. Assuming that both numbers which
> represents panadol and tylenol pills have the same prime divisors. How
> many compount divisors will it have the smallest value of the product
> of both numbers?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{210}\\
2.&\textrm{214}\\
3.&\textrm{187}\\
4.&\textrm{207}\\
\end{array}$

The official solution according to my book is to assume the following:

It states:

$\textrm{A: The number of panadol pills}$
$\textrm{B: the number of tylenol pills}$

$A=p^a q^b$
$B=p^c q^d$

According to this in order to get the minimum product of pills then $A\times B$ must be minimum.

For this to happen:

$\textrm{p<q and a>b and c>d}$

(Comment: This part it doesn't seem much sense)

Then it states: Using the notation of $\textrm{QD = quantity of divisors}$

$\operatorname{QD}(A)=(a+1)(b+1)=45$

$\operatorname{QD}(B)=(c+1)(d+1)=66$

From this it concludes that:

$a=9$

$b=4$

Assuming that the combination can only be: $9\times 5=45$

It doesn't say why it discards other choices.

and for the other number it assumes:

$22\times 3 =66$

Therefore

$c=21$

$d=2$

Again it doesn't say why it does have to be those numbers and in that order.

Then it declares:

$A\times B = p^8 \cdot q^4 \times p^{21}\cdot q^2= p^{29} \cdot q^6$

Now it comes the most weird conclusion:

$\operatorname{QD}(A\times B)= 19\times 10=190$

Hence:

It uses the formula:

$\operatorname{QD}=\textrm{prime divisors}+1+\textrm{compount divisors}$

I believe this arises from the fact that the number of divisors is equal to the number of prime divisors plus one plus the compound divisors.

Then:

$190=2+1+\textrm{compount divisors}$

Therefore it concludes:

$\textrm{compound divisors}=187$

Hence the answer is the third option.

But this doesn't make any sense. I mean at the point I reached this part I got lost.

As it can be seen I don't feel happy with this method of solution because it lacks of the proper explanation on **why it must be those peculiar divisors** it could be any other combination as well. This confuses me a lot.

As I mentioned it isn't very clear why that must be the quantity of divisors and that the smallest number of pills.

**Does it exist a way to solve this using those concepts but better explained?**

I'm lost at this ans since I feel there are many missing steps it would help me a lot if someone could help me here with an answer which would be easier to understand and the **most detailed** as possible.

Comment: "How many compount divisors will it have the smallest value of the product of both numbers?"  I can't tell what compound divisors might mean, unless it is numbers bigger than $1$ that are not prime.  Then, I cannot make any sense of the sentence in quotes.

Comment: "composite" means numbers bigger than $1$ that are not prime.

Comment: one concept that might be involved is the least common multiple: if $e = \max(a,c)$ and $f = \max(b,d)$  then $\operatorname{lcm} ( p^a q^b, p^c q^d ) = p^e q^f$

Comment: I've given an answer below but this is quite an involved question so please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: I think he used brute force and thought it was clear he had done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to be familiar with the fact that the divisors of $p^aq^b$ are all the numbers of the form $p^xq^y$ with $0\le x\le a,  0\le y\le b$. There are $(a+1)(b+1)$ of these.

So we know that
$$(a+1)(b+1)=45$$ $$(c+1)(d+1)=66.$$

Now $45=1\times 45=3\times 15=5\times 9=9\times 5=15\times 3=45\times 1$. The possible solutions of the first equation are $$(a,b)\in \{(2,14),(4,8),(8,4),(14,2)\}.$$

By the same method
$$(c,d)\in \{(1,32),(2,21),(5,10),(10,5),(21,2),(33,1)\}.$$

There are of course lots of ways of combining these. You should have a go at trying this out and for each possibility working out the number of divisors of the product of the two numbers, $(a+c+1)(b+d+1)$.

You can see that one possibility is $$(a,b)=(8,4)\text { and } (c,d)=(10,5)$$
This gives a number of divisors $19\times10=190$. Now, three of the divisors are $ 1,p,q$ and these are not composite and so we have the 'book' solution of $187$ composite factors.

**Note**

I don't think you should expect to be able to 'see' that $(a,b)=(8,4)\text{ and } (c,d)=(10,5)$ is obviously best. However if you try out some of the other possibilities you will get a feel for whether any other combination is likely to be better.

**For example**

$(a,b)=(2,14)\text { and } (c,d)=(2,21)$ gives $5\times 36=180$, a better answer! However the wording of the question concerning what is 'smallest' might mean that the product itself is smallest (although we don't know the primes). Do you have an image of the actual question?

Comment: I'm stuck on the part which refers to $(a,b)=(8,4),(c,d)=(10,5)$ is this implying multiplication?. Which posibility gives $190$ divisors?. Do you mean $(8,4),(10,5)$? Because it seems that is meant $(2,1)$. This confuses me. Although I get your idea regarding that from the two sets you mentioned I could start trying out using $(a+c+1)(b+d+1)$ to see which result gives the least value.

Comment: The author seemed to contrain the choices for $5, and 9$ and $22$ and $3$.  I have no idea why. The author states that $A$ and $B$ must be minimum. It implies that without knowing $A$ or $B$ this will be minimum when their powers are the least possible. My best *guess* is that this was the logic. You can see a caption of the original problem and the solution [here](https://i.imgur.com/uI3WTWr.png) the original source was in spanish language so I had to translate it. Does this given information helps?

Comment: I wish I could offer more but so far it seems that from your solution one has to try with all of the elements in the sets that you presented. But if you happen to see an aditional clue which I may overlooked on the original solution, please include it in your answer. *Again* it would help me a lot, if you could **explain your notation** with the $(8,4),(c,d) =(10,5)$, does this means $(c,d)=(10,5)$? I must say tat I agree that other choices your sets seem better answers but I have no idea **why** the author preferred the one resulting $190$.

Comment: (c,d)=(10,5) just means c=10,d=5.The image doesn't help me but my wife speaks Spanish  so I'll ask her when she gets home.

Comment: thanks for that. I'll be eager to know if it would ease in any way the solution of this problem. Thanks for the clarification of the notation. I'd suggest to add a space between the comma between $(8,4)$ and the $(c,d)$ because it seems that they are joined together.

Comment: You don't actually have to try every solution since if you write a few out you'll see that many of them are obviously too big.

Comment: I've had it translated now. The question itself is incorrect because  it cannot be answered unless you know the primes. Interpreting it as I did gives a sensible question but their answer contains several errors irrespective of the meaning of the question.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer and I agree with your argument about that it cannot be answered without knowing the primes. When you mentioned the errors are you referring to the statement regarding the condition that should be met for the exponents of $p$ and $q$ so as $A \times B$ is minimum?. Because that was my confusion but from your comment it seems that is a flaw in the solution.

Comment: Yes that's right - whoever wrote the solution got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you don't mind would you help me with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022896/can-the-quotient-of-a-division-of-a-polynomial-acts-as-the-residual-in-the-remai) it is about polynomials and the correct usage of the remainder theorem. I'll appreciate if you could give it a look.

Comment: Hi. Have only just got back in and seen your message. I've posted an answer now.